# Using DeleteCases to match a string pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

I am trying to remove all of the elements from a list that contain the characters `"err"` in that order.

I expect the following code to return an empty list:

```
DeleteCases[{"Aerr"}, __ ~~ "err"]
```

However it fails to recognize the pattern and will return the full List. What am I missing in the documentation for patterns? Perhaps it is an issue with `DeleteCases`, as I can use `StringMatchQ` to identify that the patterns match.

```
StringMatchQ["Aerr", __ ~~ "err"]
```

Returns `True`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First note the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) of your pattern:

```
__ ~~ "err" //FullForm
```

> StringExpression[BlankSequence[],"err"]

The pattern is a [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression), so you must use a string function, e.g., [`StringMatchQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ) instead of [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases), which is expecting a normal pattern. Here are some other possibilities:

```
list = {"Aerr"};

Select[list, Not @* StringMatchQ[__ ~~ "err"]]
Pick[list, StringMatchQ[list, __ ~~ "err"], False]
```

> {}
>
> {}

Answer (score 6):

```
DeleteCases[{"Aerr"}, _?(StringMatchQ[ "*err"]) ]
```

> {}

For versions prior to version 10:

```
DeleteCases[{"Aerr"}, _?(StringMatchQ[#, "*err"] &)]
```

> {}

Comment: While I appreciate the working example, I would have loved further explanation of how it works. I've gathered that the "?" syntax is a pattern test, but how does the "_" pattern which is for a single character match "Aerr"? Also, is it a bug that the code in my original question didn't work, or a misunderstanding of how to use patterns?

Comment: @Karl, please see Carl' Woll's answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Karl, `_` pattern matches _any Mathematica expression_;  only in string patterns it stands for a single character.